Oracle / sqlplus varchar2(32000) not working even MAX_STRING_SIZE shows EXTENDED
I am new to Oracle databaase. I have installed 23AI version. My project uses varchar2(32000) so, I have changed MAX_STRING_SIZE to EXTENDED and other sql accordinly as per oracle documentation.
I can create table with varchar2(32000) using sysdba user but for other users I am getting:
ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

This is more a comment than an answer, but the text is too long and it really looks ugly there.

You said:

I have changed MAX_STRING_SIZE to EXTENDED and other sql accordinly as per oracle documentation

What does "and other sql" mean?

This is MAX_STRING_SIZE 23ai documentation. It says that you should run

utl32k.sql script in the root and in all the PDBs in the CDB to increase the maximum size of the VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, and RAW columns

as well as shutdown/startup the database; there are quite a few steps you should have taken, so I'm just wondering whether you did that or not.

And the limit in 32K BYTES... so if the default size (NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS ) is in CHAR and the language setting is multi-byte (like AL32UTF8) : 32000 CHAR may be > 32767 BYTES.

other sql meant utl32k.sql and utlrp.sql, what is PDBs ?

Since Oracle 12c, there are CDB (container database) and PDB (pluggable database). Read about it in documentation. As of switching between them, have a look at Tim Hall's article (as kind of a shortcut, so that you wouldn't have to read vast official documentation), here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1
